# HTML/CSS - Using Custom Font / FontSquirrel

Tags: html, css, fonts

I downloaded this font (https://www.google.com/fonts/#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Underdog) and then used FontSquirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) with it.

However, I'm not sure where I should place the files in Eclipse...

This was in one of the css files that FontSquirrel generated and I placed it in my CSS file.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'underdogregular';
src: url('underdog-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('underdog-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('underdog-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('underdog-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('underdog-regular-webfont.svg#underdogregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

FontSquirrel also generated these files:

`underdog-regular-demo.html`

`underdog-regular-webfont.eot`

`underdog-regular-webfont.svg`

`underdog-regular-webfont.ttf`

`underdog-regular-webfont.woff`

Would anyone know where I should place these?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can place these fonts in path and add this path in the url like /font

Comment: but if you trust google fonts, you could use this link : `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Underdog' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`. It will automatically deliver font depending on browser type.

Comment: Thanks sivatumma, that was actually what I tried first... Unfortunately, it was working on my Nexus One emulator but not on my Samsung Galaxy S2 phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would put those font files somewhere on your web server, then adjust the `url` path in the CSS to suit. So just as you might upload your background images to an `/assets/images/` folder:

```
background-image: url("/assets/images/foo.jpg");
```

...you could upload the font files into an `/assets/fonts` directory and adjust the font squirrel CSS accordingly:

```
src: url('/assets/fonts/underdog-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('/assets/fonts/underdog-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/underdog-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/assets/fonts/underdog-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/underdog-regular-webfont.svg#underdogregular') format('svg');
```

Or, if you don't want to edit the CSS, just upload them to the same directory as the CSS file.

Comment: Thanks Olly! I just copied them to the same CSS directory like you suggested :)